# Как назвать действие когда ребенок в ответ высовывает язык и гримасничает

Tags: вопрос

Как назвать действие когда ребенок в ответ высовывает язык и гримасничает

Comment: Действие ребёнка уже названо: высовывает язык и гримасничает. Вы не упомянули — в ответ на что. Не зная этого, квалифицировать ответное действие однозначно нельзя.

Comment: *квалифицировать ответное действие однозначно нельзя* - а зачем вообще его квалифицировать? Его **назвать** просят.

Comment: Автор сам определит нужное слово, тогда и задачку можно будет решить. Если промолчит, будем просить закрыть этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Это разновидность детской *дерзости* (https://childdevelop.ru/articles/upbring/2962/), соответствующий глагол - *дерзить*; словесный вариант дерзости - *грубость* (*грубить*).

Comment: Дерзость - **действие**?

Comment: В этом контексте - конечно: ребёнок дерзит в описанной форме. Не дерзновением же называть его действие.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы немного поплыли с определениями. Дерзость, конечно, может быть поступком, но именно поступком... По вашей ссылке - какое-то филологическое недоразумение.

Comment: *Не дерзновением же называть его* - а зачем вообще его называть чем-то, что совершенно не подходит по контексту?

Answer (score 0):

Ну, допустим, **кривляется** он. Зачем вам еще какое-то название **действия**?